# No overload matches this call when removing event listener

Tags: typescript, html5-canvas

When trying to set some event listeners to load an image, I get the following errors.

```
const loaded = (ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D, hexSize: number) => {
    console.log(`Drawing ${plottable} on ${hex}`);
    ctx.drawImage(plottable.img as CanvasImageSource, hexCenter.x - hexSize / 2,
        hexCenter.y - hexSize / 2, hexSize, hexSize);

    plottable.img?.removeEventListener('load', loaded);
    plottable.img?.removeEventListener('error', loaded);
}

if (plottable.img.complete) {
    loaded(this.ctx, this.hexSize);
} else {
    plottable.img.addEventListener('load', () => loaded(this.ctx, this.hexSize))
    plottable.img.addEventListener('error', function() {
        alert(`${plottable.displayName}'s image failed to load.`);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a fat arrow function is used when adding the event listener, it also needs to be used as the 2nd parameter like so:

```
plottable.img?.removeEventListener('load', () => loaded);
plottable.img?.removeEventListener('error', () => showError);
```

Comment: I did as you said and the type checking indeed stopped complaining. Can you point me to where the documentation say this for people who might see this post?